# Grails SpringSecurityFacebook plugin DefaultFacebookAuthDao error

Tags: facebook, spring, grails, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

I am using Grails 2.0.4. With the application I want to add facebook authentication to access my application. I already have Spring Security plugin installed for the current Grails version and it is working fine. I want to scale it to have access from facebook users as well. For that I've installed [SpringSecurityFacebook](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-facebook) plugin. SpringSecurityCore plugin version is 1.2.7.2 & SpringSecurityFacebook plugin version is 0.15.

With SpringSecurityCore plugin I've configured domain classes for User & Role which are User.groovy & UserRole.groovy respectively. I've let SpringSecurityCore plugin to create joining class for User & UserRole class, so it has created a database table user_authorities. Now here comes a problem with SpringSecurityFacebook plugin. When I run the application with both of these plugin installed, it states that SpringSecurityCore plugin configured successfully and SpringSecurityFacebook plugin configured successfully. And after that it fires an error which is mentioned below.

```
ERROR facebook.DefaultFacebookAuthDao  - Can't find authority join class (PersonAuthority). Please configure 'grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName' value, or create your own 'List<GrantedAuthority> facebookAuthService.getRoles(user)'
ERROR facebook.DefaultFacebookAuthDao  - UserDetailsService from spring-security-core don't have method 'createUserDetails()'
```

Now, my question is do we require to have joining table's domain class created in our application, as the SpringSecurityCore plugin states that it is optional. And if require then is it mandatory to have our custom logic or it's original logic to create domain with that name will work?

Suggestions are welcome...

Answer (score 0):

Your app configured to use `PersonAuthority` class name, but you said that you're using `UserRole` class. `PersonAuthority` is a [default value](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/4%20Required%20and%20Optional%20Domain%20Classes.html#4.3%20PersonAuthority%20Class) from Spring Security Core

Just configure `grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName` with correct value, like:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName='UserRole'
```

Comment: In my case the database table for joining User & UserRole is user_authorities. So for Grails domain I need to create UserAuthorities class, right? And the code will remain same as mentioned on http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/4%20Required%20and%20Optional%20Domain%20Classes.html#4.3%20PersonAuthority%20Class

Comment: You can use existing domain, as I described

Comment: I've done so. Added the line in Config.groovy file. Now it gives different error.

It gives error:

`ERROR facebook.DefaultFacebookAuthDao  - UserDetailsService from spring-security-core don't have method 'createUserDetails()'`

Comment: It can work after this error, but usually it means that there're misconfiguration in spring-security-core plugin. what version do you use?

Comment: Spring Security Core version 1.2.7.2

Comment: No, it is not working. I got this error in the same version of Spring Security Core plugin.

Comment: Current latest stable version of the plugin is 1.2.7.3. Do you thing upgrading to that version will solve the problem?

Comment: As of now it is an Error in log only. I've not noticed any problem regarding Spring Security Facebook plugin, which is possibly due to the above mentioned error from Spring Security Core plugin.

Can you explain why it is going to look for `createUserDetails()` method, please?

Comment: because it tries to use createUserDetails from Core plugin, if it exists. instead of own implementation